# Return 404 when GET the resource using ObjectId of MongoDB?

Tags: python, mongodb, eve

I am using python 3.4.2, eve 0.7, flask 0.12 and MongoDB as my DB.

Here's my eve schema code:

```
'item_title': 'abc',                                                                                                                                         
'id_field': 'ObjectId',                                                                                                                                        
'item_lookup_field': 'ObjectId',                                                                                                                               
'item_url': r'regex("[\w]+")',                                                                                                                                 
'query_objectid_as_string': True
```

When I try to get the resource using Mongo object id, it returns 404.

```
'item_title': 'abc',                                                                                                                                         
'id_field': 'custom_field',                                                                                                                                        
'item_lookup_field': 'custom_field',                                                                                                                               
'item_url': r'regex("[\w]+")',                                                                                                                                 
'query_objectid_as_string': True
```

It works fine when I use any other custom field. 
I've also tried the code below. Also returns 404.

```
'item_title': 'abc',                                                                                                                                         
#'id_field': 'ObjectId',                                                                                                                                        
#'item_lookup_field': 'ObjectId',                                                                                                                               
'item_url': r'regex("[\w]+")',                                                                                                                                 
'query_objectid_as_string': True
```

Comment: The `id_field` setting just sets the name for the ID field used. Does the resources have a field named `ObjectId`? If you changed this after POSTing them, they may not have yet.

Comment: No resource doesnot have a field name object id. It have field `_id`

Comment: That's why you cannot GET the resource. Your `item_lookup_field` is set to `ObjectId`, but it doesn't exists. Try to create new resources from now on using these settings, the new resources should have the expected ID field and work as desired for the lookup.

Comment: I found the solution. Thank You @gcw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
'id_field': '_id',  # Name of field                                                                                                                                      
'item_lookup_field': '_id', # Name of object field ex. mongo object id here

'query_objectid_as_string': False
```

Since the `query_objectid_as_string':True it queries the database as string not object . So it wont find . So it returns 404